# Installing Anchor Failed -

Tags: anchor, installation

I'm trying to install Anchor on my Unbuntu WSL Env. I'm getting this error. Would appreciate any guidence.

```
    $ avm install latest
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("api.github.com")), port: None, path: "/repos/coral-xyz/anchor/tags", query: None, fragment: None }, source: hyper::Error(Connect, ConnectError("dns error", Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Temporary failure in name resolution" })) }', src/lib.rs:177:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a DNS error, you may have blocked the domain via pihole, etc, or you may be running in a container environment (Docker, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Just had similar issues, you can try:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked
```

if you get an error saying `Add --force to overwrite`, run this:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor anchor-cli --locked --force
```

Then try `anchor --version`

This should work and return

```
anchor-cli 0.28.0
```